# Azure functions - durable functions, SetCustomStatus not updating

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I created a durable function based on Microsoft examples from the pattern of "Async HTTP APIs".

In my code flow I wish to update the "SetCustomStatus" without using the "await contextReq.CallActivityAsync".

Is it possible? since my durable function stays in "Pending" status, and the "customStatus" doesn't get updated.

Some code snippet:

```
[FunctionName("UpdateItemsWithProgress")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")]HttpRequestMessage req,
        [OrchestrationClient]DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        dynamic jsonMessage = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
        try
        {
            string contentType = req.Content.Headers?.ContentType?.MediaType;

            if (contentType == "application/json")
            {
                    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("updateTransitItem", jsonMessage);

                    log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

                    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
            } else
            {
                return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, null);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, e.Message);
        }

    }

    [FunctionName("updateTransitItem")]
    public static async Task<object> RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext contextReq)
    {
        dynamic dynObj = contextReq.GetInput<object>();
        contextReq.SetCustomStatus("Working...");

        // doing stuff

        contextReq.SetCustomStatus("1");

        // doing stuff

        contextReq.SetCustomStatus("2");

        // doing stuff

        return "Success"

     }
```

Comment: An orchestrator function that doesn't schedule some sort of async work (callActivity, createTimer, etc.) is a bit strange to me. Do you want to use Durable Functions because the work performed in your orchestrator takes a long time to complete?

Answer (score 1):

This may be answered here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/767d5be5-4ba9-4b53-9838-9e32dfa7bdb3/azure-functions-durable-functions-setcustomstatus-not-updating?forum=AzureFunctions.

To copy the answer --

> I don't believe the status is persisted anywhere until the activity is called. So if you never call one, it will never be updated.